# Can isc-dhcpd be configured to remove DNS records when leases expire?

Tags: bind, isc-dhcp

I've configured my dhcp server so it can successfully add records to a private DNS zone when it issues a lease for a client.

I never see it removing a lease however.

Is it supposed to do so or is there some configuration param I should be setting to get this behaviour?

I'm using the 'interim' style of dynamic DNS updates.

Comment: To my knowledge ISC dhcpd is supposed to clean up DNS entries for expired leases based on the data stored with the lease.

Comment: Indeed it cleans the records in the standaed update scheme. See this link: https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01091

Comment: I believe you, but for my own satisfaction I'll have to check the logs more carefully to see if it does remove them. Thx for mentioning the 'standard' method.  I must have followed an older guide and was using 'interim'.  I've cleaned up my leases and zone files and converted to standard.